# What does a QA Architect do in a team, and what skills are needed for this job?

Tags: team, qa-developer, qa-architect

I saw a job ad for a QA Architect. I realized that I don't know what is the role of QA Architect in a team.

So, what does a QA Architect do in a team and what skill does he need to have both in terms of soft-skills and technical skills?

Also I would like to know if working as a developer, system engineer, QA Engineer and QA Developer is relevant for that position.

Comment: What responsibilities were listed in the job ad?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I never see common agreement on any software-related titles.

In some shops where I have worked "Architect" implies a thinker, not a doer. For QA Architect, it means someone who thinks about QA, researches and suggests improved methods and metrics. Sometimes it's someone who trains others.

In other shops, "Architect" just means "very Senior". It's the top-level tester in the shop. Nothing more.

Your mileage may vary. Consult the job ads themselves for hints as to what "QA Architect" means for that particular company. And if you apply and get an interview, ask lots of questions. That is the *only* way you will know.

Comment: Seems titles should be universal but Companies never seem to support this, so annoying.

Comment: @Shane That's the nature of natural language. On one side it is very flexible and can capture many terms, on the other side it can be very ambigous. Look at the term of architect in everyday life. One can have skills to design small house, other -- bridges, and yet another sky-scrapers, depending whether we are talking about civil engineering or buildings.

Answer (score 6):

A qa architect is a person who design the building block of qa process. Basically this is more relevent to test automation where many things comes in picture. So his role is to place and consult the optimized way to place the block so that whole system is stable economic  scalable, fast and optimized. Test automation uses a lot of resources like machines. Tools and services so this guy is responsible to stablish the system which follow the above mentioned guidelines.

Answer (score 5):

I could give you my best guess, but really you ought to ask them.  Titles and responsibilities vary from one company to the next.

Comment: Although responsibilities vary from company to company maybe there is some common agreement on what a QA Architect does.

Comment: I never see common agreement on any software-related titles.

Answer (score 3):

Two interesting reads, they offer great insights on senior QA roles:

- [What is a test architect?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alanpa/what-is-a-test-architect)
- [From John Morrison's Blog - Test Architect](https://blogs.oracle.com/johnmorrison/entry/test_architect)

Answer (score 1):

This article has a great definition of what a QA Architect is:
https://medium.com/@maomrtnz/whats-a-qa-architect-9efc98037255

Answer (score 0):

QA Architect can also referred for individuals who build frameworks for QA tests and processes. Should I use Nunit, Xunit, JUnit, Selenium, Robotium, or one of the many other ums? Should I send test details to a log, to a DB, to a server? Do I use Jira, Gemini, etc... These are all questions an architect type person needs to answer. The specific title may vary depending on company, but the generic requirement to be able to answer these questions is a must.